# Paste Value all the cells in a given sheet if Cell has Vlookup formula..

Tags: loops, excel, excel-2007, vba

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE($B$100);INDIRECT("2011.xls!"&D$101;0);3;0)
```

I have a sheet to send other people but i cannot send 2011.xls because it contains secret information. How can i copy-paste value all the cells in that sheet ("Centers") which has a formula like
     =VLOOKUP(VALUE($B$100);INDIRECT
or contains VLOOKUP    ?

Normally i would break link but because i have linked the table array with Indirect its not seen as a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This procedure loops through all cells on the sheet and changes all VLOOKUP formulas to values:

```
Sub RemoveVlookupFormulas()
    Dim rng As Range
    With Worksheets("Centers")
        For Each rng In .UsedRange
            If rng.Formula Like "*VLOOKUP*" Then rng.Formula = rng.Value
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellente ! Thanks very much Rachel ! (again) :)